# Python Nested Progress Bars for Spherical Harmonic Coefficients using Rich

Tags: python, progress-bar, rich

I have a set of nested for loops for spherical harmonic coefficients, and I'd like to use [Rich](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to show the progress of the nested components.

```
import numpy as np
from time import sleep

l = 32
for ll in np.arange(l):
    # I want a progress bar for ll here

    for mm in np.arange(-1*ll, ll+1):
        # I want a progress bar for mm here
        sleep(0.01)
        print(f"l: [{ll}], m: [{mm}]")
```

This github issue provides a partial solution https://github.com/Textualize/rich/discussions/2272, but assumes that each sub loop has the same number of entries:

```
from rich.progress import Progress
from time import sleep

with Progress() as pb:
    t1 = pb.add_task('inner', total=10)
    t2 = pb.add_task('outer', total=100)

    for i in range(100):
        for j in range(10):
            print(f"Verbose info! {i, j}")
            sleep(0.1)
            pb.update(task_id=t1, completed=j + 1)
        pb.update(task_id=t2, completed=i + 1)
```

While I love [tqdm](https://tqdm.github.io/), and have achieved partial success using the `leave=False` keyword, I'm not satisfied with how I loose the last output once both loops have been completed

```
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep

l = 32
for ll in tqdm(
    np.arange(l),
    desc=r" ",
    disable=False,
):

    for mm in tqdm(
        np.arange(-1 * ll, ll + 1),
        leave=False,
        desc=r" ",
        disable=False,
    ):
        sleep(0.01)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want the progress bars when it's running, but you don't care if they remain once the program is finished? But you do care about the print output?

Unfortunately, most progress bar libraries do not handle arbitrary printing to the screen when using progress bars well or at all. [Enlighten](https://pypi.org/project/enlighten/) was specifically written for this use case.

The example below explicitly calls the `close` and `stop` methods, but you can also use [context managers](https://python-enlighten.readthedocs.io/en/stable/patterns.html#context-managers) to do this implicitly. You can also adjust the value of `leave` to suit your needs. Many more options, such as [color](https://python-enlighten.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#color) and custom [formatting](https://python-enlighten.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#counter-format), are described in the [documentation](https://python-enlighten.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).

```py
from time import sleep

import enlighten
import numpy as np

manager = enlighten.get_manager()

l = 32
l_pbar = manager.counter(total=l, desc='l', leave=False)
for ll in np.arange(l):
    l_pbar.update()
    m_pbar = manager.counter(total=ll * 2 + 1, desc='m', leave=False)

    for mm in np.arange(-1*ll, ll+1):
        m_pbar.update()
        sleep(0.01)
        print(f"l: [{ll}], m: [{mm}]")

    m_pbar.close()
l_pbar.close()
manager.stop()
```